# VBA Copy range values and paste in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, range

I have made a program, that allows the user to enter the year and team, that they are on. It print the values to a data sheet. When the user click on a commandbutton, the code will print the values to a calendar.
My question is, can this be made smarter?

```
If Worksheets("DATA").Range("B2").Value = "2018" And Worksheets("DATA").Range("B3").Value = "Team 3" Then
'January
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J4:J34").Copy
    Worksheets("2018").Range("D3:D33").PasteSpecial xlValues
'February
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J35:J62").Copy
    Worksheets("2018").Range("H3:H33").PasteSpecial xlValues
'March
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J63:J93").Copy
    Worksheets("2018").Range("L3:L33").PasteSpecial xlValues
'April
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J94:J123").Copy
    Worksheets("2018").Range("P3:P33").PasteSpecial xlValues
'May
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J124:J154").Copy
    Worksheets("2018").Range("T3:T33").PasteSpecial xlValues
'June
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J155:J184").Copy
    Worksheets("2018").Range("X3:X33").PasteSpecial xlValues
'July
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J185:J215").Copy
    Worksheets("2018").Range("AB3:AB33").PasteSpecial xlValues
'August
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J216:J246").Copy
    Worksheets("2018").Range("AF3:AF33").PasteSpecial xlValues
'September
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J247:J276").Copy
    Worksheets("2018").Range("AJ3:AJ33").PasteSpecial xlValues
'October
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J277:J307").Copy
    Worksheets("2018").Range("AN3:AN33").PasteSpecial xlValues
'November
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J308:J337").Copy
    Worksheets("2018").Range("AR3:AR33").PasteSpecial xlValues
'December
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J338:J368").Copy
    Worksheets("2018").Range("AV3:AV33").PasteSpecial xlValues
End If
```

On the Sheet1 sheet, the dates are listed in C

[image: 2018]

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Userformdata]

Comment: Almost everything can be made smarter, if there is enough details about the data layout to pick up patterns etc.

Comment: You want to copy July into 4 columns - "AB3:AF33"?

Comment: @paulbica i want to copy the value of ex the values of january in Sheet1 'Team 1 A' to 2018 H3:H33  and february sheet1 'Team 1 A' to L3:33 to sheet '2018' etc.

Comment: I can see what your code is doing, I'm asking specifically about the July copy action: `("Sheet1").Range("J185:J215").Copy: ("2018").Range("AB3:AF33").PasteSpecial` (copy to **AB3:AF33** - 4 columns)

Comment: @paulbica No that's a mistake, sorry :-) - it's supposed to be AB3:AB33 - I have attached the 2018 sheet as well

Comment: With your data, the Yearly plan can clearly be generated on change of Year. How do you make use of the A/B/C for each Team (assuming the A is column J)?

Comment: @PatricK i haven't coded that part yet. But i will make user choose between A/B/C and the get a slightly different plan, depending on the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to make it easier to update the ranges to be copied (mapping):

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyData()
    Const START_ROW = 3

    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA").Range("B2").Value = "2018" And _
       ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA").Range("B3").Value = "Team 3" Then

        Dim yr As Object, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

        Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2018")

        Set yr = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        yr("J4:J34") = "D"      'Jan
        yr("J35:J62") = "H"     'Feb
        yr("J63:J93") = "L"     'Mar
        yr("J94:J123") = "P"    'Apr
        yr("J124:J154") = "T"   'May
        yr("J155:J184") = "X"   'Jun
        yr("J185:J215") = "AB"  'Jul
        yr("J216:J246") = "AF"  'Aug
        yr("J247:J276") = "AJ"  'Sep
        yr("J277:J307") = "AN"  'Oct
        yr("J308:J337") = "AR"  'Nov
        yr("J338:J368") = "AV"  'Dec

        Dim mnth As Variant, arr As Variant, toRng As String
        For Each mnth In yr
            arr = ws1.Range(mnth)
            toRng = yr(mnth) & START_ROW & ":" & yr(mnth) & UBound(arr) + START_ROW - 1
            ws2.Range(toRng) = arr
        Next mnth
    End If
End Sub
```

---

This is not ideal because there are still hard-coded values for all ranges but the columns are not the same size and I can't see the pattern for that

Comment: it looks great, but dosen't paste any values in the 2018 sheet.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is; I created a new file with 3 sheets - Sheet1, DATA, and 2018, ran your code and it worked, then created the new code and it worked as well. You may need to step through the code and monitor the variables in the For loop

Comment: Lol it works now, i made an error. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I’m glad you worked it out. If you give me the details of the error you had I can append it to my answer so others can avoid it

Comment: I made an important update that will be easier to maintain in the long run by removing all hard-coded ranges

Comment: The other one was easier for me to understand. Does this know if it’s fx Team 1 A, Team 1 B or Team 1 C? - because the work schedule is slightly different. By using the old code you provided i had to copy the code 18 times to cover all A, B and C through team 1-6. I used a If statement to get ‘2018’, ‘Team 3’ and ‘A’ to get it to work with all the schedules. Is it too complicated Paul?

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know - I rolled back to the previous version, as the main reference. If you’re interested in making it more dynamic you can see the update in the Edit history of the answer (version 6)

Comment: If you got the time, i would be happy if you want to take a look at it @Paul and see if you in any way can optimize it. Can i send the workbook to you? :-)

Comment: Sure, send it dexxus @ rogers.com

Answer (score 0):

Because date and time in Excel is stored as a number of days, the source row can be found with:

```
=Date(2018, Column() / 4, Row()) - Date(2018, 1, -1)
```

and the source column index with:

```
=Match(Data!B3 & "*", '2018'!3:3, 0)
```

and combined in VBA:

```
y = [DATA!B2]

Sheet1.[3:33 (D:D,H:H,L:L,P:P,T:T,X:X,AB:AB,AF:AF,AJ:AJ,AN:AN,AR:AR,AV:AV)].Formula = _
    "=If(C3, Index('" & y & "'!$A:$Z, Date(" & y & ", Column() / 4, Row()) - Date(" & y _
    & ", 1, -1), " & Evaluate("Match(DATA!B3 & ""*"", '" & y & "'!3:3, 0)") & " ), """")"
```

Comment: correct me if i’m wrong, but this code includes the year, so if i for example, continued the plan in sheet1 to 2019, by just dragging the down, it wouldn’t be a problem?

Comment: @ClausThaulovSkeelKristensen if 2019 is on the same Sheet1 after column AV and you have a "2019" sheet, you can try `y = 2019` and updating the column ranges that are before `)].Formula`